# Why do the critical values of the chi-square distribution increase with degrees of freedom?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, chi-squared-distribution

This makes no sense to me since we usually want more degrees of freedom and the t-and F-distributions reflects this by demanding smaller critical values for significance. The tables I have found only display 1-30 degrees of freedom for the Chi-square which seems odd given that t- and F-distribution tables usually show at least 100+ as that would be the standard if you have a decently large dataset to subtract number of variables and constant from the number of observations to get your degrees of freedom.

Can anyone make it clear to me how I should read such a table (just click the first Google search picture and you will see the same). Or tell me if I have completely lost it. I get that it looks different in a graph but the values makes no sense.

Comment: The chi-squared distribution arises as the sum of squares of DF independent standard Normal variables.  Since squares are nonnegative, this makes it obvious that both the *average* and the *variance* of chi-squared distributions increase with DF.  Although that doesn't prove that critical values must also increase with DF, it strongly suggests it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $t$ distribution is set up so that the critical value converges to 1.96 as $n \rightarrow \infty$. It is for a one d.f. hypothesis.  The $F$ distribution is similar to a $\chi^2$ distribution divided by its d.f.  This always makes things confusing, because e.g. you can add a variable to the regression model and have $F$ decrease even when the variable is important.  $\chi^2$ is such that adding information (e.g., a predictor) increases the statistic.  The d.f. is the number of opportunities that the statistic had to be large.  More opportunities come from adding variables or adding categories in a frequency (contingency) table.  The more opportunities (d.f.) the higher the critical value you must achieve to have evidence above the noise level.